# Use mercurial "out of tree"

Tags: mercurial

I'm looking to use a repository from "out of tree", that is, the `.hg` directory is not located in a parent directory of the working directory.  As an example, consider that my repository root (`.hg`) is at `~/src/dotfiles`. I wish to `diff ~`, as though the working copy was checked out at `~`, but the `.hg` folder is actually at `~/src/dotfiles/.hg`. The `-R` option doesn't allow this,

```
$ hg -R ~/src/dotfiles diff ~
abort: /Users/anacrolix not under root '/Users/anacrolix/src/dotfiles'
```

I'd prefer not to have `.hg` in `~`, or use a symlink.

Answer (score 1):

The .hg directory is always a sub-folder of the repository root and there is no way to change that.

Depending on the usage scenario behind your question you might want to look at some of the available repository hooks. You could use for instance the changegroup and / or commit hooks in order to run a script which updates another repository when new changes are added to your repository, e.g. for deployment purposes

Comment: Could you quote or reference a definitive source for your first paragraph?

Comment: Simply look at mercurial sources, e.g. localrepo.py, from the definition of class localrepository  : http://selenic.com/repo/hg/file/efa094701a05/mercurial/localrepo.py#l191

Answer (score 0):

See [Mercurial Documentation](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Repository) for a reference of the first paragraph!